# index.js?1dce:612 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'super' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

Here is my code in main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate';

import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import BaseDialog from './components/BaseDialog.vue'

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);
app.use(Vuelidate);

app.component('base-dialog', BaseDialog);

app.mount('#app');
```

After that I'm getting an error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'super' of undefined".
There is something wrong here:

```
while (Vue.super) {
    Vue = Vue.super;
  }
```

.

If I'm writing `import Vue from 'vue'`, and than `Vue.use(Vuelidate)`, I'm getting new error that there is no Vue in 'vue'.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I'm facing the same issue right now

Comment: ane suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there:

```
app.use(Vuelidate);
```

According to vuelidate docs this is valid issue of plugin usage in new version and since Vue 3 support was introduced:

```
import { useVuelidate } from '@vuelidate/core'

export default {
    setup () {
        return { v$: useVuelidate() }
    }
```

https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/#getting-started-1